# FitSharp and x86 .Net dll

Tags: .net, fitnesse, fitsharp

I have an ActionFixture that is compiled into a x86 dll.  When I run the test from fitnesse test starts but never finishes.  Is there any way to get fitnesse to run a dll compiled as x86?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you compile your dll's as 32 bit (x86) you may encounter problems when running fitnesse tests using the fsharp runner.exe.  The solution I have used to resolve the problem is to run corflags.exe against the runner.exe.  This will effectively change the runner to a 32 bit application. corflags comes as part of the Windows Development SDK which can be downloaded off the Microsoft website.

```
corflags runner.exe /32BIT+
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what's happening. Run with the GUI runner and see if you get an exception. See http://www.asoftwarecraft.com/2010/01/troubleshooting-with-fitsharp-and.html

Comment: Mike,  I didn't give the most accurate description of the issue above. (Maybe because it was late on Friday and I was already thinking of the weekend).  I did actually get an exception message which was a BadImageException.  Which is why I mention x86 above. I have found a solution and will post the answer below